# Wordpress: Custom URL segment for viewing by custom post meta

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post meta for specifying the particular "show" a post is associated with, and I would like to be able to list posts with a particular show name using a URL similar to this:

```
/shows/show-name/
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: You might consider using a custom taxonomy (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) for this rather than a post meta.  The URL structure you want would already be baked in by WordPress.